# How to draw a circle after a circle is detected using SimpleShapeChecker? (Accord.net Portable)

Tags: c#, image-processing, windows-phone-8.1, aforge, accord.net

So, I am trying to draw a circle after I found a circle using the SimpleShapeChecker() from the Accord.net portable library using this code:

```
// locate objects using blob counter
BlobCounter blobCounter = new BlobCounter( );
blobCounter.ProcessImage( bitmap );
Blob[] blobs = blobCounter.GetObjectsInformation( );
// create Graphics object to draw on the image and a pen
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage( bitmap );
Pen redPen = new Pen( Color.Red, 2 );
// check each object and draw circle around objects, which
// are recognized as circles
for ( int i = 0, n = blobs.Length; i < n; i++ )
{
     List<IntPoint> edgePoints = blobCounter.GetBlobsEdgePoints( blobs[i] );

     Point center;
     float radius;

     if ( shapeChecker.IsCircle( edgePoints, out center, out radius ) )
          {
          g.DrawEllipse( redPen,
               (int) ( center.X - radius ),
               (int) ( center.Y - radius ),
               (int) ( radius * 2 ),
               (int) ( radius * 2 ) );
          }
}

redPen.Dispose( );
g.Dispose( );
```

However, both the System.Drawing.Graphics and System.Drawing.Pen shows an error:

```
"inaccessible due to its protection level"
```

Therefore I can't really do anything after I've found a circle. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `System.Drawing` types provided in the *Shim Drawing* NuGet package, are only intended for internal use by the corresponding *Portable Accord* (and *Portable AForge*) libraries.

Instead of using `Graphics` to draw on the `bitmap` image object, you should instead cast `bitmap` to the appropriate image type on the platform you are working on (`WriteableBitmap` on Windows, `Android.Graphics.Bitmap` on Android and `CGImage` on iOS) and use the drawing tools available on each specific platform.

Comment: I see. Thanks. I got it working. I've used WriteableBitmapEx to draw a circle.